# How to get last N documents with mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have found some information to accomplish this in mongoDB, but I need it with mongoid. So I can do something like:

`User.last(7000).each do ...`.

I'm using:

- MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
- Mongoid 2.6.0

Thanks!

Comment: Try to translate JS solution to Mongoid. I bet it'll work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Now I found a solution from mongoid [origin](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html#sorting):

```
User.all.desc('_id').limit(7000)
```

It sorts the users in descending order according to the id.

Comment: IMPORTANT! Assuming you have 9000 records if you do u = User.all.desc('_id').limit(7000) and then u.delete it would delete the 9000 records! Just happened to me on a production app. Luckily I always do a fresh backup before doing such things.

Comment: @Pod you should convert to array `to_a` after `limit()` (before destroy), read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20368143/1297435

Comment: ...and to get the nth record from last `User.all.desc('_id').offset(n).first`

Comment: Note: the "origin" link referenced in this answer is now "Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations can directly be chained to a Model in rails irrespective of the ORM used. We don't need to use `all`. You could just do the following

```
User.limit(3000).desc('_id')
```

This will only return the Mongoid criteria. To see the data you can chain `.all` to the criteria. You can directly do operations on the criteria also, without having to chain `.all` or `to_a`.