# Rails Mongoid model query result returns wrong size/length/count info even when using limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, count, mongoid, limit

When querying on a certain model in my rails application, it returns the correct results, excerpt the `size`, `length` or `count` information, even using the `limit` criteria.

```
recipes = Recipe
  .where(:bitly_url => /some.url/)
  .order_by(:date => :asc)
  .skip(10)
  .limit(100)

recipes.size # => 57179
recipes.count # => 57179
recipes.length # => 57179
```

I can't understand why this is happening, it keeps showing the total count of the recipes collection, and the correct value should be 100 since I used `limit`.

```
count = 0
recipes.each do |recipe|
  count += 1
end

# WAT
count # => 100
```

Can somebody help me? 
Thanks!

--
Rails version: 3.2.3
Mongoid version: 2.4.10
MongoDB version: 1.8.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo%3alength):

> **- (Integer) length**
>   Also known as: **size**
>
> Get's the number of documents matching the query selector.

But `.limit` doesn't really alter the query selector as it doesn't change what the query *matches*, `.offset` and `.limit` alter what segment of the matches are *returned*. This doesn't match the behavior of ActiveRecord and the documentation isn't exactly explicit about this subtle point. However, Mongoid's behaviour does match what the MongoDB shell does:

```
> db.things.find().limit(2).count()
23
```

My `things` collection contains `23` documents and you can see that the `count` ignores the `limit`.

If you want to know how many results are *returned* then you could `to_a` it first:

```
recipes.to_a.length
```

Comment: Using Mongoid 4.0.2 here, if you don't want to load all of that into memory you can do `.where(...).limit(100).count(true)`. This will respect the limit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, in newer Mongoid versions (not sure which ones), you can simply use `recipes.count(true)` and this will include the limit, without needing to query the result set, as [per the API here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped%2FQuery%3Acount).

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of mongoid (5.x), `count(true)` no longer works. Instead, `count` now accepts an options hash. Among them there's `:limit` option

```
criteria.count(limit: 10)
```

Or, to reuse whatever limit is already set on the criteria

```
criteria.count(criteria.options.slice(:limit))
```